# How to Sum time values from a specific month in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have the following view in my `views.py`:

```
timesheet = Timesheet.objects.annotate(
    total_time=ExpressionWrapper(
        ExpressionWrapper(F('out') - F('entry'), output_field=IntegerField()) -
        Coalesce(ExpressionWrapper(F('lunch_end') - F('lunch'), output_field=IntegerField()), Value(0)),
       output_field=DurationField()
    )
)
```

This allows me to calculate the total worked hours in a single day, which is then looped on a table.

But, I need to be able to Sum all the total worked hours from each specific month.

Is this achievable?